# Index 1 is either negative or above rows count

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

```
DataView dv = ds.Tables["Unit"].DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = SqlWhere;
dv.Sort = SortList.SelectedValue.ToString();
PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource();
page.DataSource = dv;
page.AllowPaging = true;
page.PageSize = Int32.Parse(ResultList.SelectedValue);
page.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " +
                                                        page.PageCount.ToString();
// Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
cmdPrev.Enabled = !page.IsFirstPage;
cmdNext.Enabled = !page.IsLastPage;
invList.DataSource = page;
invList.DataBind();
public int CurrentPage
{
    get
    {
        // look for current page in ViewState
        object o = this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"];
        if (o == null)
            return 0; // default page index of 0
        else
            return (int)o;
    }

    set
    {
        this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value;
    }
}
```

But it is now showing error like this in `invList.DataBind();`

```
Index 4 is either negative or above rows count.
```

**Description**

```
 An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
 Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it 
 originated in the code.
```

**Exception Details**

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 1 is either negative or above rows count.
```

can anyone help?

Comment: @RabNawaz its still showing that error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bindings which invList.DataBind is setting up are referring to a view such as dv. This is a guess as it'll be elsewhere in your code.

For data from a multi row table to be shown in a simple control, the binding needs to know which row to use, this error is saying that whatever is determining the row is returning "Index 4" (row 5... index starts at 0) where there are 4 or fewer rows in the table.

Check your row navigation, especially after changing the contents of the underlying table, make sure its current row is set to a valid number.