# how to make Repeater Results as different pages

Tags: asp.net, paging

```
DataTable newdt = new DataTable();
newdt = DataSetHelper.Join(ds.Tables["Unit"], ds.Tables["Location"], new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables["Unit"].Columns["Location_Id"] }, new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables["Location"].Columns["Location_Id"] }, "locationName");
DataView dv = ds.Tables["Unit"].DefaultView;
Repeater.DataSource = dv;
Repeater.DataBind();
```

now all the Results are displaying on one page, 
i want to change it into different pages.

how can i do that? please help

### Update 1

```
dv.Sort = SortList.SelectedValue.ToString(); 
PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource(); 
page.DataSource = dv; page.AllowPaging = true; 
// page.PageSize = Int32.Parse(ResultList.SelectedValue); page.PageSize = 10; 
page.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage; lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " + page.PageCount.ToString();
cmdPrev.Enabled = !page.IsFirstPage; 
cmdNext.Enabled = !page.IsLastPage; invList.DataSource = dv; invList.DataBind();
```

Comment: use repeater pagination

Comment: Do you want paging in `repeater` [Example Link](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx)

Comment: @AmitSingh thanks for your quick reply, but how to do it?

Comment: @Shekhar now all the pages are displaying in a single page using repeater.. i want to make it to different pages

Comment: go through the link provided by me http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx

Comment: @Shekhar i have used this but showing out of range exception .. it is showing error " index value is negative or above row count "

Comment: Put your code in your question.

Comment: @Shekhar this is the error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033107/index-1-is-either-negative-or-above-rows-count

Comment: @Shekhar it is showing index value as negative or above row count sequentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Put Pagination in `Repeater`.Try this [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31819/Pagination-with-Repeater-Control) for more information

Comment: it is showing error " index value is negative or above row count "

Comment: ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString() to ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()

Comment: can you please tell me how i can edit this code (dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345 ) without a query and also i have results in my dv

Comment: you can not do itwithoput quert it have no means without query....get only specific record and bind it to ur repeater.....what is ur sql query u r using now...

Comment: you can use ur own simple query it not neccessary to write linq

Comment: so are you saying while implementing the program you specified, whether i could use my query again ?

Comment: yeah u can use but just use lyk this...Select Row_Number() OrderBy(Any Column Name) as RowNum, * from (Your Query) where Row>currentpage*PageSize and Row< (currentpage*PageSize+PageSize)...it gives u specific record for ur page